# What is the simplest way to compute $f_Z(z)$ when $Z = \min(X, Y), X \sim U(0, 5), Y \sim U(0, 10)$?

Tags: probability, order-statistics

Note that $Z \in (0, 5)$, so we have

$$
    F_Z(Z \leq z) = \begin{cases}
    ? & z \leq 5 \\
    1 & z > 5
    \end{cases} \\
$$

Now need to compute $F(Z \leq z | z \leq 5)$.

$$
F(Z \leq z | z \leq 5)  = F(Z \leq z | Y > 5, z \leq 5)P(Y > 5, z \leq 5) + F(Z \leq z | Y < 5, z \leq 5)P(Y < 5, z \leq 5) \\
F(Z \leq z | Y > 5, z \leq 5) = F(X \leq z) = \frac{z}{5} \\
F(Z \leq z | Y < 5, z \leq 5) = 1 - P(X \geq z | Y < 5, z \leq 5)P(Y \geq z | Y < 5, z \leq 5) = 1 - (5 - z)^2/25 \\
F(Z \leq z | Z \leq 5) = z/10 + 1/2 - (5-z)^2/50
$$

So we have
$$
F_Z(Z \leq z) = 
\begin{cases}
z/10 + 1/2 - (5-z)^2/50 & z \leq 5 \\
1 & z > 5
\end{cases}
\\
\therefore
f_Z(z) = 
\begin{cases}
1/10 + (5-z)/25 & 0 \leq z \leq 5 \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Is this the correct approach? Is there an easier approach to what I have taken here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> s there an easier approach to what I have taken here?

I suggest you a simple graphical approach:

Frist of all observe that

$$f_X(x)=\frac{1}{5}$$

$$f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{10}$$

in the following rectangle

[image]

Thus, by definition

$$\mathbb{P}[Z>z]=\mathbb{P}[X>z;Y>z]=\frac{(5-z)(10-z)}{50}$$

(area of the purple rectangle $\times f(x,y)$)

and thus

$$F_Z(z)=1-\frac{(5-z)(10-z)}{50}$$

derivating you get your density

$$f_Z(z)=\frac{15-2z}{50}\cdot\mathbb{1}_{(0;5)}(z)$$

... this result matches with yours but I think this procedure is very fast.

Comment: The graphical approach is a lot more elegant.